# Need explanation to call autocompletion for a custom swift struct memberwise initializer in separate file in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, struct

I have encountered a small problem but got the solution on my own just recently.
I declared a struct in a separated file in Xcode. Suppose it is Television.swift where the struct Host located inside. But whenever I call the struct for the first time in a separate file, it appears no memberwise initializer in autocompletion.

```
struct Host {
    var host: Int
}
```

This happened in a class scope.

If I call the memberwise initializer for the second time inside a class scope, it appears correctly as I desired to be.

Class scope initialization
[image]

But, if I call the struct in a function scope, the memberwise show up correctly.

Call initializer in function scope

[image]

Does Xcode encourage us to avoid any custom type initialization inside the class in the separate file? Or is there something I've left behind when learn to code in Swift or learn Xcode?

Comment: This behaviour occurs even when the struct is in the same file as the class. You can always work around this y typing `.` after `Host`. `init` will always show up.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you so much. Its really helpful. But I still wonder why did the behaviour happen.